# Expose DB2 data as XML / Query DB2via XML

Tags: xml, drupal, drupal-6, db2, xml-rpc

I have a client who has a sort of data warehouse stored in DB2. For a variety of reasons, the data must remain on this platform.

The client is considering implementing an open-source CMS (Drupal) which runs in MySQL. The client needs to be able to execute a bunch of pre-defined queries against the DB2 database from the remote application.

Drupal appears to interact well with XML data from other systems. It was suggested that we use something like XML-RPC to execute the queries against DB2.

I am very familiar with SQL Server and pretty familiar with MySQL, but I have no experience with DB2 and no understanding of its capabilities or limitations.

Is there any way that we can use something like XML, XML-RPC, or even http to initiate queries against a DB2 database?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: might be interesting for you - all db2 xml possibilities http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing and consuming XML in DB2 is very easy.   DB2's pureXML implementation of the SQL/XML, XPath and XQuery standards is one of the most complete in the marketplace.

Creating stored procedures to produce the XML would be my recommendation.

I'd suggest the following book as an excellent guide -

http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0138150478&S_TACT=105AGX01&S_CMP=TILE&ca=dti-ibmpresspurexmlcook&ca=dth-i

If you need any help then don't hesitate to drop me a line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the Services module. It will assist you there. You can also implement xmlrpc without it, but it has some nice features.